# Global button click with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to have a redux action where i can globally listen to a button click on all components without changing a value or something. I should just be an event where I want to trigger functions on the different components.
Does anyone knows an easy and clean way how to do it?

Best regards!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried an action where I returned the state like the following "{...state}". For JS it's a changed dummy value, so the event triggers. The problem is if I listen to changes with "useEffect" that it triggers on load without the click event. There are ways to prevent this, but I'm searching for a cleaner solution.